# Draw and Rotate a Equilateral Triangle in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am stuck trying to draw and rotate an equilateral triangle using libgdx. To get started I created an arbitrary equilateral triangle centered at (50f, 50f) with side length 30f. I want to use ShapeRenderer to draw my triangle and rotate according to this code:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.identity();
shapeRenderer.translate(50f, 50f, 0); // center of triangle
shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);


shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, world.ship.rotation);

shapeRenderer.triangle(50f-15f, 50f-13f, 50f+15f, 50f-13f, 50f,50f+13f);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

The problem is that the triangle rotates around a different axis than the center.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.identity();
shapeRenderer.translate(150f, 150f, 0);
shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);


shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, world.ship.rotation);

shapeRenderer.triangle(0f-15f, 0f-13f, 0+15f, 0f-13f, 0f,0f+13f);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

You have to center the triangle at the origin, because libgdx can only do rotations relative to the origin. Then you translate your rotated shape (remember that transformations are done in reverse order of your code according to documents, so in my code `rotate()` goes first then `setColor()` then `translate()`).